# Qt Raise window to foreground without giving focus

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have ***some*** situations where I'd like to raise my window to the foreground *without* giving it focus. I was using platform-specific dependencies to do this before (in Python), but I'm hoping this is possible directly in Qt.

I've tried a number of different combinations with `.raise_`, `.activateWindow`, `.setWindowState` and toggling `Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating` with `.setAttribute`, but I've had little success in being able to choose between giving and not giving focus. There doesn't seem to be a direct way to achieve this, but it feels like there's some gimmicky combination here that would let you do it anyway.

Comment: `self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus)`? Note that this will *completely* prevent focus on the window, so you won't be able to use the keyboard there.

Comment: How about show window always on top?